# Scroll down one "scroll unit" on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a link div which scrolls down on click; like one scroll down of the mouse wheel does or one click down on the arrow of the scroll bar.

Is there a method in CSS or jQuery/JavaScript to do that?

And also several scrolls, like 3 scroll downs?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Can include `html` , `js` tried at Question ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no such thing as a scroll unit. This is device dependent.

But to make the window scroll when clicking something is simple with jQuery.

```
$(function(){
  $(".clickScroll").click(function(e) {
    document.body.scrollTop += 10;
  });
});
```

This will scroll the view 10 units, of some measure, down on every click.

See this [plunker for a full example](http://plnkr.co/edit/szBGn0rmcxz9H5xLEd0p?p=preview).

Comment: Yes, this. Mouse wheels and up/down arrows will vary depending on device, save your self the headache and pick a standard unit.

Comment: Thanks! You halped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You should try something like:

**HTML**

```
<div onclick="myFunction()"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
myFunction = function(){
    var myVar = $(window).scrollTop();
      $(window).scrollTop(myVar+300);
}
```

MyVar gets your position on the page.
I hope I've been helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I couldn't get this to work but it might be a solution too.